# tkinter, pack inside grid and propagation not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a button with a fixed size. So, I created a Frame (grid) with the size I want and then a child Button (pack) inside of the Frame that takes all the space.

Here is a minimal example:

```
window = tk.Tk()
frame1 = tk.Frame(window, bg="#ffffff", height=50, width=100)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame1.grid_propagate(0)
#frame1.propagate(False)       #  <----- This line makes it work.
button1 = tk.Button(frame1, bg="#000000")
button1.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
```

Without the commented line above, I expected that it would work (having a rectangle of the specified size), but I get a small square. Why is it not working?

I was not able to find documentation on that `.propagate()` function. I only found about the `grid_propagate()` and `pack_propagate()` functions.

Comment: `.propagate` is the same as `.pack_propagate`. As you are using `.pack` on the widgets inside the frame, `.grid_propagate` isn't going to do anything.

Comment: I need to use `frame1.pack_propagate(False)` even though `frame1` is a grid?

Comment: When you use `frame1.grid(...)`, you tell the parent of `frame1` (which is `window`) that it should use the grid manager. Inside `frame1`, you are using the pack manager.

Comment: I see. If you write this as an answer, I will accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have 2 containers: `window` and `frame1`. When you use `frame1.grid(...)`, you actually tell the master of `frame1`, which is `window` that it should use the grid manager. When you use `button1.pack(...)`, you tell the button's master (`frame1`) that it should use the pack manager inside itself.

So when you use `frame1.grid_propagate(...)`, you tell the grid manager (that doesn't manage the widgets inside `frame1`), that it should do something, so it ignores you.